# How to put numbers, separated by spaces, outputted by a program into an array in Bash shell script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Suppose my Python script output the following line of numbers:

```
python3 myscript -> 12 93 12 83
```

Now, I would like to break this line of output `12 93 12 83` up into an array, so that I can execute a command with (some of) these as arguments.

If there is a simpler way of achieving this, please tell me. Otherwise, how do I break space separated output up into an array?

Answer (score 4):

Use `read`, which can do the splitting to create the array :

```
IFS=" " read -r -a array < <(python3 myscript)
```

Obviously, the above assumes that spaces are used to separate the numbers.

If you want to split on spaces and newlines, as suggested by CharlesDuffy :

```
IFS=$' \n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(python3 myscript && printf '\0')
```

The `-d ''` causes a null byte to be treated as a record separator.

Then, you can expand the array with `"${array[@]}"` (the double quotes are important to avoid word splitting).  `[@]` means "all array elements", similar to how `"$@"` means "all positional parameters".  To extract a single element, you can use `"${array[1]}"`, `"${array[2]}"` (where the index often will be a variable).

You can iterate over array elements easily:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

If you want a loop that handles empty arrays, many Bash versions will fail using the expansion above ; you can then use the following syntax :

```
for element in ${array[@]+"${array[@]}"}
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

You can retrieve the number of items in the array with `"${#array[@]}"`.

Comment: Could you provide a small example of how to index the array elements? What does @ refer to? And could I also use read to split at newlines?

Comment: @Fred, given the explicit request for indexing, you might also discuss `"${array[0]}"`, `"${array[1]}"`, etc.

Comment: @Shuzheng: If you want to spilt at newlines I suggest to use bash‘s `mapfile`: `mapfile -t array < <(python3 myscript); declare -p array`

Comment: @Fred - Why is `IFS=" "` necessary?

Comment: @Shuzheng, that specifies spaces -- which your question specifies are what separate the values -- as the characters used to split items apart. If you wanted to explicitly allow both spaces and newlines, that would be IFS=`$' \n'`, or such. Granted, the default (which is spaces, tabs and newlines) will work for you too, but writing code to be explicit means you can safely reuse it in a wider array of contexts.

Comment: (...btw, since this is so close to being a pedantically-correct answer, might also add the `-r` argument to `read`, making it `read -r -a array`. Or, to fully answer the side question about how to split on both spaces and newlines with `read` vs `mapfile`: `IFS=$' \n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(python3 myscript && printf '\0')` -- which has the benefit of making the `read` fail if `python` does, *and* of being compatible with bash 3.2).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - When I try to read documentation about `read`, I get documentation of a `read()` C-function. How do I see the documentation of the `read` we are using? Also, is the `IFS` an environment variable that `read` uses?

Comment: Why doesn''t make example on newlines work?
`IFS=$'\n' read -a array < <(echo 1$'\n'2$'\n'3$'\n'4)` - this doesn't split at newlines. Thanks you for your help btw. @CharlesDuffy.

Comment: @Shuzheng `read` reads one "record" of input, and splits the elements read into an array.  The default record separator is a newline.  In order to use newlines as element separators within a record, it is necessary to prevent them from terminating records.

Comment: How can that be done - prevent newlines from terminating.

Comment: @Shuzheng The `-d ''` option of `read` sets a null byte as the record separator, and prevents newlines from terminating a record.

Comment: @Shuzheng, I already showed a way to do that in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561204/how-to-put-numbers-separated-by-spaces-outputted-by-a-program-into-an-array-in/43561253?noredirect=1#comment74173864_43561253).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thanks for you help; it has been a pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$()` to capture the output of commands and direct to an array:

```
IFS=" "
set -f
my_array=($(python myscript))
# Do stuff with array
some_command "${my_array[@]}"
set +f
```

What this does is set the separator to a space character, and turns globbing off, then takes the output of `myscript` and sends it to an array, with you can use later to pass as arguments for another command

Comment: I may only need some of them.

Comment: Also, note that all-caps variable names are specified for names with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas lowercase variables are reserved for application use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an array?  Suppose you want to use the 2nd and 4th entries.  You could simply use the positional parameters and do:

```
set -- $(python3 myscript)  # Set positional parameters
some_cmd $2 $4
```

Or, you could name the values with:

```
python3 myscript | { read col1 col2 col3 col4
some_cmd $col2 $col4
}
```

Comment: Granted, you *can* get away with a bunch of the shortcuts here if we assume sane IFS values and that the output will only ever be numbers, but it's reasonable to assume that an answer will be used by people other than the OP, and that the OP will reuse practices they learn here in other circumstances where the guarantees in the question may not hold.

Comment: Yes, these solutions assume a specific format of the output of myscript, and sane values for IFS.  Reader beware, reader be informed, reader learn from any mistakes that may arise if these conditions are not met.